# Typing in command line (cmd) is very slow after SSH

Tags: windows, command-line, ssh

First: I don't mean about the login process.

When I use SSH to login in a server it start to type slow (ssh root@1.1.1.1 e.g). I mean when I press a key it doesn't do nothing until 1sec after I didd. And this only happens when I ssh in any server even when I ssh in a local server. If I don't ssh and just use the promt for 'normal' usage (create folder, move into folder, delete, etc etc) in my pc it does as normal (not blink, not slow) I had tried to use other consoles such as Hyper, OhMyZ, PowerShell, etc... All of them same result.

My Pc:

- Ram: 32GB
- S.O: W10 Pro 64Bits (comp 18362)
- Processor: AMD Ryzen 7 1700

Comment: How do you define a local server? What does long and MTR show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you are connecting to a remote server and if the connection is not very good it will take time to send the data.